# Como atualizar titulo da página com notificações?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um script que atualiza o título da página e coloca quantas notificações o usuário possui antes do titulo atual. Porém como é dinâmico e atualiza essa pagina para verificar se existem novas notificações ele está dando problema no titulo. Vou dar uma exemplo:

Tenho 01 notificação e o titulo atual da pagina é Home, então o titulo fica assim "(1) Home", conforme vai verificando se existe novas atualizações o titulo vai ficando assim: "(1) (1) (1) (1) (1) Home". Queria uma ajuda para que isso não ocorresse!

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
document.title = "('.$total_notifi.') "+title;
```

Este é o script que tenho no momento, onde a tag em PHP `$total_notifi` é o número de notificações do usuário.

Comment: Acho que você deve executar a mudança do código somente se o `$total_notifi` for `>` que o atual `$total_notifi`. No processo de verificar quantos notificações ele tem, retorne o valor somente se for maior. Se for igual, não execute nada.

Comment: Bom dia! Não tem como saber o funcionamento do seu código e aonde esta a falha, pois você só postou um pedaço, a atualização é ajax? O seu código aqui `'.$total_notifi.` do jeito que está misturado com o javascript e php não faz sentido, ele não pode ser reproduzido, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e só depois de ler edite a pergunta.

Comment: Toda vez que você busca o `title` você não está removendo a quantidade de notificações. anterior.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade ele apenas traz o valor, no caso, 1, 2 ou 3, a logica é um SELECT que faço no banco e me traz esse valor!

Comment: @LeonardoCarmo Entendo, mas o problema não é esse, o problema é como você colocou o CÓDIGO aqui na pergunta, não é possível entender se o problema é PHP ou JS, se a solução pode ser php, se atualiza com ajax ou não, coisas do tipo. Você esta dizendo que traz de um select, ok é php + mysqli api, mas não diz como é induzido a soma. Ou seja o código não tem sentido que pudesse ser respondido, por isto forneci uma resposta que tenta fazer um PARSE do titulo existente e por JS mesmo ele atualiza: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108449/3635 - o setInterval é apenas pra simular ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que, provavelmente você está pegando novamente o título toda vez que vai atualizá-lo. Por isso está sendo concatenado o `(1) (1)` ...

Você pode salvar o título do documento em uma variável logo que rodar o script e mantê-lo como se fosse uma constante, uma única vez. Posteriormente você substitui título atual com o valor da variável que pegou logo que o script foi executado, contendo o primeiro título.

```js
/*
 * Coloquei um título para exemplificar. No caso, CONST_TITLE pegaria
 * o primeiro valor do próprio título do documento, e.g:
 * 
 *
 *    var CONST_TITLE = document.title;
 *
 */
 
 
var CONST_TITLE = 'Meu título incrível';

function setTitulo(notificacoes) {
  document.title = '(' + notificacoes + ') ' + CONST_TITLE;
}

setTitulo(10);
console.log(document.title); // (10) Meu título incrível

setTitulo(100);
console.log(document.title); // (100) Meu título incrível

console.log(CONST_TITLE);   // Meu título incrível
```

Comment: obrigado! realmente deu certo! obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Podem ser um problema no PHP se não está usando a soma pelo JavaScript, mas se for no front-end então vou explicar o que pode estar ocorrendo.

Supondo que o código na verdade seja isto (*já que o que foi postado não tem sentido*):

```
<?php
echo 'document.title = "(' . $total_notifi . ') " + title;';
```

Então a atualizações agora ocorre no *front-end* por incremento, da maneira que esta aqui o código consegue atualizar o título acessando o titulo já vindo do php (back-end)

Algo como:

```
document.title += "(1)";
```

Se o problema é realmente no javascript, então você deve converter pra `int` usando `parseInt` por exemplo e também fazer os tratamentos necessários, algo como:

- **javascript:**

  ```
  //Valor que virá do ajax ou js que você fez e será somado
  function atualiza(soma) {
      var re = /^\(\d+\)/g;
      var res = document.title.match(re);

      //Pega o total no titulo
      var atual = res && res[0] ? parseInt(res[0].replace(/\(|\)/g, "")) : 0;

      //Remove o total e os `()` do titulo
      var titulo = document.title.replace(re, "");

      document.title = "(" + (atual + parseInt(soma)) + ") " + titulo;
  }

  setInterval(atualiza, 1000, 1); //Adiciona +1 (terceiro parâmetro)
  ```
- **html:**

  ```
  <title>(<?php echo $total; ?>) Home</title>
  ```

  No entanto como eu já citei, o problema pode ser no php.

Note que o `(<?php echo $total; ?>)` é opcional e se a atualização veem do ajax, como é no Facebook ou Twitter, ou seja o script aqui consegue se adequar a qualquer título que sem precisar setar em uma variável, exemplos de páginas que o `(1)` será adicionado:

home:

```
<title>Home</title>
```

Blog:

```
<title>Blog</title>
```

E o Ajax (exemplo Jquery) seria algo como:

```
$.ajax("update.php").done(function(data) {
     atualiza(data);
});
```

Após executar ele em qualquer página o resultado será algo como:

home:

```
(2) Home
```

Blog:

```
(2) Blog
```

Ou seja desta forma que fiz o título é atualizado independente do conteúdo original.

Comment: Na verdade estou precoupado com SEO, cada pagina tem seu titulo, então eu resgato o titulo atual da pagina, definido anteriormente, verifico se existe notificação, caso exista eu atualizo esse titulo colocando o valor antes dele, porem como dito na primeira resposta eu posso salvar esse titulo predefino em uma variavel e depois atualizar o titulo pegando essa variavel e adicionando o valor das notificações

Comment: Se está preocupado com SEO, então a minha resposta é um melhor caminho ao meu ver, já que o titulo inicial pode ser algo como `(1)`, apenas um titulo em HTML e ele faz o **parsing** do titulo e depois joga o `(1)` na frente... Todavia ainda sim o código tal como é descrito e as soluções propostas levam a uma certa confusão de entendimentos.

Comment: @LeonardoCarmo Se está preocupado com SEO, então a minha resposta é um melhor caminho ao meu ver, já que o titulo inicial pode ser algo como (1), apenas um titulo em HTML e ele faz o parsing do titulo e depois joga o (1) na frente, pois no código o `(1)` é desnecessário (opcional) :D ... Todavia ainda sim o código tal como é descrito e as soluções propostas levam a uma certa confusão de entendimentos.

Comment: @LeonardoCarmo atualizei a resposta, dá uma lida ;)

Comment: Meu nivel em JS não é muito bom rs, mas entendi sua ideia, vou estruturar aqui e testar

Answer (score 3):

Olá, você pode esta retirando a sua notificação anterior antes de colocar a nova da seguinte forma.

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
title = title.substring(title.indexOf(")"), title.length);
document.title = "('.$total_notifi.') "+title; 
alert(title);
```

Comment: Se tiver mais de um digito na quantidade de notificações não irá funcionar o `substring`, vai cortar o número ou sobrar o parenteses. =/

Comment: Verdade, só usar str.indexOf(")")