# Como colocar notificações no Title?

Tags: javascript, html

Seguindo o exemplo do facebook

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugestão para evitar que fique algo como *"(5) (4) (3) (2) (1) meu titulo"* quando o esperado deve ser *"(5) meu titulo"* e para utilização de ajax: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108449/3635

Answer (score 2):

Vocês pode fazer isso utilizando uma função no `javascript`:

```
function changeTitle() {
    var titulo = document.title;
    var numero = 5; // Número de notificações a ser exibidas
    var novoTitulo = '(' + numero + ') ' + titulo;
    document.title = novoTitulo;
}
```

Aí depende de você alterar a variável `numero`pra pegar a quantidade de notificações que seu usuário tem.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, ja consegui! :)

Answer (score 1):

No caso do facebook e tantos outros sites que usam essa técnica, o resultado é obtido por meio de frameworks reativas, exemplo [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), etc...

na tag `title` tem o seguinte

```
<title>{{notificações}} Facebook</title>
```

Caso o WebSocket detectar uma nova notificação, a interpolação "notificações" irá atualizar com o valor correto, esse conceito é chamado de [Two way data binding](http://voidcanvas.com/react-tutorial-two-way-data-binding/)